# Conditional removal of trailing zero's from time

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm looking to remove only the trailing zero's from times in excel. i.e. 0700 should display as 07, but 1630 should remain as 1630.

I've been able to do this within a UDF, but it's starting to slow my sheet down. Is there any way of achieving this as an in-built function?

Comment: Just after posting i've worked it out through a formula: IF(RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hhmm"),2="00" etc to get my desired result.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it, because it may help someone else, and accepting it closes the question.

Comment: "closes" might be the wrong word here, rather I'd say "marks the question as solved".

Comment: @Jerry at least stops it being pushed forever by the community script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question has already been answered, other approaches might include:

```
=TEXT(A1,IF(MOD(A1*24,1),"hhmm","hh"))
```

or:

```
=TEXT(A1,IF(OR(MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1)),"hhmm","hh"))
```

In both cases, the return value is a string (the value is no longer internally represented as a number).

Comment: Thank you chillin, far more succinct than what i came up with!

Answer (score 2):

Answer as requested:

=IF(RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hhmm"),2="00",
LEFT(TEXT(A1,"hh"),2),
TEXT(A1,"hhmm"))

Have to use the TEXT to identify the time as a string, otherwise excel sees it as a decimal.